# Win8.1 Refresh deleted my folder on desktop

Tags: windows-8.1, refresh

I just restarted my laptop today because it was saying there was problem with one of the disks and it needed to restart to fix it, so I restarted it. But when it was booting it came across to a problem and was not able to boot and showed me some options. So under "refresh" it was saying it won't delete any files but it may delete apps, which was fine for me so I chose this and waited about 15-20mins to do the job. 
Once it was done windows started normally and I got my old desktop with old names of my files. Everything was fine except I was not able to find the folder I have been working on for the last two months (which I did not backup stupidly, though I intended a few times but was lazy and I had no worry about losing the data). The folder was just at the middle of my desktop with the name "equation derivation". I can not freaking find it. All of my other folders are here but not THE ONE that is supposed to be. I am just freaking out here....  I had many matlab codes and PDF files inside this folder.

- I tried to restore but there is no restore point because of freaking "refresh".
- I tried to use a recovery program to show me some files, but it found almost nothing.
- There is a  "windows.old" file which has user accounts but in that one there are fiveusers:  Administrator, guest, ibaha_000, Public, UpdatusUser. Last three folder's creation date is today and first two folders creation date is when I bought the laptop (2014-HP-Envy) .  When I go inside ibaha_000 folder (or any others) there are some folders inside it and I try to go inside "Desktop" because the folder I am trying to find was on desktop, but there is nothing there at all. So "windows.old" did not restore any of my files....
- When I search for any of the matlab file names or folder names or PDF file names on the search of PC, I get no result. 
  Please someone help me with this I really need someone's help to recover my files that I spent two months... (And I know I should have backed it up but there was no sign of anything like this I would have, stupid me...)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recover my files from the hard-disk with professional "active at" recovery program that ran about 8 hours to pull out data.

Refresh might delete your files because it might recognize some of your programs or text files as windows program files, as it happened in my case. It didn't delete all of my matlab files, it deleted the folder I have lots of .m files.

So before refreshing windows, BACKUP your data, that's the solution.